# Storyboard.Begin crashes the App in Anniversary Edition

Tags: c#, uwp, winrt-xaml

We have a **UWP Project** that is targeting **Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393).**

We have a **Storyboard** that we trigger in Code-Behind. It was working before; before we targeted the Win 10 Anniversary Edition.

But now, every time the **StoryBoard.Begin** is called, it suddenly crashes the App.

Below is the XAML:

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform />
</Grid.RenderTransform>
<Grid.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="MoveX">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="Grid_TemplateRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" To="-520">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Oscillations="0" Springiness="1" />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</Grid.Resources>
```

And here is the code-behind:

```
var storyBoard = senderGrid.Resources["MoveX"] as Storyboard;
storyBoard.Completed += (s, o) => MoveX_Completed(item, deleteElementRef);
storyBoard.Begin();
```

Anyone else experience and fixed this?

EDIT: Here is the MoveX_Completed method:

```
    private void MoveX_Completed(CompositeTransform item, Canvas deleteElementRef)
{
    try
    {
        item.TranslateX = 0;
        if (deleteElementRef.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            deleteElementRef.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            deleteElementRef.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }

        var type = deleteElementRef.DataContext.GetType().Name;

        if (type == "CheckItemViewModel")
        {
            var vm = deleteElementRef.DataContext as CheckItemViewModel;

            if (vm != null)
                vm.RemoveOrVoidFromCheckCommand.Execute(null);
        }
        else if (type == "CheckExtensionDataItemViewModel")
        {
            var vm = deleteElementRef.DataContext as CheckExtensionDataItemViewModel;

            if (vm != null)
                vm.RemoveOrVoidFromCheckCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        POSEventSource.Log.Warn("Error while swiping to delete check item, MoveX_Completed: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `senderGrid`? What does you `MoveX_Completed` method do? Without a repro it's hard to say how to fix your issue.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about `MoveX_Completed` method ?

Comment: sendergrid is simply a Grid. I have added more info about MoveX_Completed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a known bug. It has something to do with the oscillation set to 0.

Workaround is to use ExponentialEase.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f77a9df6-deeb-4a3a-b165-3cbb2b2c9b55/uwp-elasticeaseoscillation-causes-crash-in-anniversary-update-sdk?forum=wpdevelop